# non-exhaustive pattern matches on list of tuples

Tags: haskell

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but I have been unable to get the pattern matching on checkDiff to work in the code below. GHCi report "non-exhaustive patterns in function checkDiff. The code is:

```
import Data.Array.Unboxed

primes :: [Int]
primes = 2 : oddprimes ()
  where 
    oddprimes () = 3 : sieve (oddprimes ()) 3 []
    sieve (p:ps) x fs = [i*2 + x | (i,True) <- assocs a] 
                        ++ sieve ps (p*p) ((p,0) : 
                             [(s, rem (y-q) s) | (s,y) <- fs])
     where
      q = (p*p-x)`div`2
      a :: UArray Int Bool
      a = accumArray (\ b c -> False) True (1,q-1)
                     [(i,()) | (s,y) <- fs, i <- [y+s, y+s+s..q]]

takePrimes :: [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]
takePrimes [] = []
takePrimes [x] = []
takePrimes (x:y:zs) = if y - x > 2 then (x,y) : takePrimes (y:zs) else takePrimes (y:zs) 

checkDiff :: [(Int,Int)] -> Int
checkDiff [] = 0
checkDiff [(0,_)] = 0
checkDiff [(_,0)] = 0
checkDiff [(a,b)] = sum $ [x | x <- [(a + 1)..(b - 1)], totalFactors a == totalFactors (a + 1)]

totalFactors :: Int -> Int 
totalFactors n = length $ [x | x <- [2..(div n 2)], rem n x == 0]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

`checkDiff` only handles lists of length zero and one. It is probably called with a longer list, triggering the non-exhaustiveness error.

You should turn on warnings with the `-Wall` flag. If you do, GHC will report such problems at compile time instead.

Comment: How did you figure out that checkDiff handles lists of length zero and one?

Comment: @Amateur `[]` is a list of length 0, `[(0, _)]`, `[(_, 0)]` and `[(a, b)]` are all lists of length 1 and that's all the patterns you have.

Comment: Thanks chi. I'm still new to Haskell. I have a lot to learn. Thank you.